# How to use horizontal recycler view and a linear layout with some child using without definate height?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have used a recyclerview and Linear layout with some child then i covered the the both in a scroll view then recycler view item is not inflate. as we gave definite height all work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F1F1F1"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="teastall.com.netpe.MainCode.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerViewMainOffer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_mainFindServices"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_delivery" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Find Service"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Provided Service"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="#111111" />
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_mainExploreMarket"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_delivery" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Find Service"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Provided Service"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#111111" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_mainAssistivePay"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_delivery" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Find Service"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Provided Service"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="#111111" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_mainDocValut"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                       <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_home_delivery" />
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:orientation="vertical">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Find Service"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="14sp" />
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Provided Service"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to use the these type of layout design but without definite height using layout weight or wrap and match parent attributes only.

Comment: insert your picture representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set orientation of recyclerview horizontaly

```
  android:orientation="horizontal"
```